# Postgres Count Function for monthly transactions, counting distinct only

Tags: postgresql

I am counting the size of my teams within a department.  All employees have an employee ID beginning with "E" and then a designating number (i.e. "0", "1", etc) to denote which team they are on.

I have the following query in Postgres to count the size of the teams, but the problem is that with this query, I get a lot of rows that are empty, because some months are duplicated.  For example, the row containing "May/2016" may be duplicated 3 times, with only 1 row containing the actual team counts.

```
select to_char("Date", 'Mon/YYYY') as "Date",
 sum(case when l_part LIKE 'E0%%' then count end) as "ACCOUNTING",
 sum(case when l_part LIKE 'E1%%' then count end) as "SW",
 sum(case when l_part LIKE 'E2%%' then count end) as "SUPPORT",
 sum(case when l_part LIKE 'E3%%' then count end) as "CALLCENTER",
 sum(case when l_part LIKE 'E4%%' then count end) as "ADMIN",
 sum(case when l_part LIKE 'E5%%' then count end) as "MARKETING",
 sum(case when l_part LIKE 'E9%%' then count end) as "MANAGEMENT"
from (
 select left("Type",4)as l_part, count(*),"Date" from 
  "Transactions" group by "Date",l_part
 ) p group by "Date"

 order by min("Date");
```

If I can just get the count down to one row per month/yyyy, and order by the date that would be helpful and less confusing.  Any tweaks to my attempt appreciated.

Here is what populates, as an example using September 2015:

This is what I get:

```
DATE  |   ACCOUNTING |  SW | SUPPORT | CALLCENTER | ADMIN  | MARKETING  |
Sep/15|              |     |         |            |        |            |
Sep/15|              |     |         |            |        |            |
Sep/15|      1       |  2  |    1    |     5      |   5    |    3       |
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - I tried to replace my query with yours as follows:

        `from ( select left("Type",4)as l_part, count(*),"Date" from 
          "Transactions" where "Date" <> '' group by "Date",l_part
          ) p group by "Date"`

But it says there is "invalid input syntax"
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: ""
LINE 11:       "Transactions" where "Date" <> '' group by "Date",l_pa...
                                                                         ^

Comment: sorry I was still typing - Postgres points at the '' portion and state invalid input syntax?

Comment: check this `select left("Type",4)as l_part, count(*),"Date" from "Transactions" where "Date" is not null group by "Date",l_part`

Comment: Yes, that returns a result.  However, I'm still left with the problem of many rows are returned that have the mon/yyyy column populated, but all the other fields are empty.

I don't know how to exclude these rows that have the empty fields.

Comment: If possible give sample data and table definition

Comment: and try this also : - http://hastebin.com/mamaqituco.sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your issue is the GROUP BY clause, which I think is solved using [DATE_TRUNC()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC). Not sure if you need the where clause.

```
SELECT
      to_char(DATE_TRUNC('month',"Date"), 'Mon/YYYY') as "Date"
    , SUM(CASE WHEN left("Type",4) LIKE 'E0%%' THEN 1 END) AS "ACCOUNTING"
    , SUM(CASE WHEN left("Type",4) LIKE 'E1%%' THEN 1 END) AS "SW"
    , SUM(CASE WHEN left("Type",4) LIKE 'E2%%' THEN 1 END) AS "SUPPORT"
    , SUM(CASE WHEN left("Type",4) LIKE 'E3%%' THEN 1 END) AS "CALLCENTER"
    , SUM(CASE WHEN left("Type",4) LIKE 'E4%%' THEN 1 END) AS "ADMIN"
    , SUM(CASE WHEN left("Type",4) LIKE 'E5%%' THEN 1 END) AS "MARKETING"
    , SUM(CASE WHEN left("Type",4) LIKE 'E9%%' THEN 1 END) AS "MANAGEMENT"
FROM "Transactions"
WHERE "Date" IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
      DATE_TRUNC('month',"Date")
ORDER BY
      DATE_TRUNC('month',"Date")
```

> btw: Instead of SUM() an alternatve using COUNT() would be:

```
SELECT
      to_char(DATE_TRUNC('month',"Date"), 'Mon/YYYY') as "Date"
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN left("Type",4) LIKE 'E0%%' THEN 1 END) AS "ACCOUNTING"
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN left("Type",4) LIKE 'E1%%' THEN 1 END) AS "SW"
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN left("Type",4) LIKE 'E2%%' THEN 1 END) AS "SUPPORT"
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN left("Type",4) LIKE 'E3%%' THEN 1 END) AS "CALLCENTER"
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN left("Type",4) LIKE 'E4%%' THEN 1 END) AS "ADMIN"
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN left("Type",4) LIKE 'E5%%' THEN 1 END) AS "MARKETING"
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN left("Type",4) LIKE 'E9%%' THEN 1 END) AS "MANAGEMENT"
```

COUNT() increments by one for any NON-NULL value it encounters.